# Wordpress: Desactivar el auto-formatting de etiquetas </p>

Tags: html, wordpress

Lo que me trae hoy aquí es algo común en wordpress por lo que vi estos días de investigación.

Pego un HTML al crear un post:

```
<p><strong>Virtud Inicial:</strong> Elige una virtud cultural beórnida entre: [bootmodal post="gran-fuerza"], [bootmodal post="coraza-de-piel"], [bootmodal post="hermanos-de-los-osos"], [bootmodal post="nocturno"], [bootmodal post="pasteles-de-miel-horneados-dos-veces"].</p>
```

y el problema con esto es que me cierra la etiqueta "p", después del primer shortcode y luego me inserta otra etiqueta "p" junto a la etiqueta "p" de cierre al final, dejándome un párrafo vacío.

Probe todos los remove_filter que lei por internet, incluso desactive el editor por bloques que trae wordpress, aunque estaba seguro que eso no era porque usaba el bloque html. Tambien probe 4 plugins que vienen con esta función, pero al parecer hay algo en el funcionamiento de Wordpress que no lo logro entender.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: que plugin está haciendo el shortcode?